# java convert a english letter to unicode

Tags: java, unicode

I want to know how to create a program that converts a input english letter into a unicode decimal?

For example, I enter the letter E, it will output 69. sth like that.

I have already tried a simple casting char to int, but don't know how to create an input scanner for char, looks like char doesn't allow to have an input scanner..

here is what I want to achieve, but it doesn't work:

```
char x = input.next(); 
int a = (int) x; 
System.out.println(a);
```

thanks your help

Comment: What happened to the code you wrote? Why did it not work?

Comment: Have you tried simply casting char to int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because .next() returns a String.

Instead, read the first character of the string returned.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String temp = input.nextLine();
char ch = temp.charAt(0);
int a = (int) ch; 
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your char value to int as follows

```
char e = 'E';
int unicode_e = (int) e;
System.out.println(unicode_e);
```

Comment: @edkai You should provide all the information that you have in the question to let all of us see all the information more clearly. In a comment it's more difficult to see what your problem is.